# Question regarding baking animation to deformation(DEF) bone

Tags: rigging, export

Trying a new method of rigging, whereby the deformation bone [DEF] is separated with the target[TGT] bone. The TGT bone will have it transformation copy to the DEF bone. This is to prevent bug from occurring when exporting to game engine.

The guide I came across stated to only bake the DEF bone.

However, as far as I know, the animation is created by only using the TGT bone, hence that is where all the keyframe information is located. So, if I only bake the DEF bone, the baked animation will not contain any "actual" animation.

So, am I approaching the method wrongly ? Blender file is provided

[image]

Comment: When you export the project to FBX, format with which you can work in the game engine, the bake animation option creates keyframes for all def bones, and remove the constraints that contain these. Also if you check "Only Deform Bones" when exporting, TGT bones will not be exported.

Comment: I see, so that how it done. Just for clarification, for the  " check "Only Deform Bones" when exporting" part.  Blender is way of  identifying deform bone is  through naming convention or the bone with keyframe information ?

Comment: No, only bones that have the "Deform" option activated in the properties of each bone are identified as deformation bone for export. [Screenshoot](https://imgur.com/a/VF9xmJ1)

Comment: oh, i see. ok I have a better understanding now. Thank you so much